What Windows API can be utilized to update device driver?
Device is detected under Device Manager under Other devices as 802.11ac NIC device. I need to automate driver update in same way as it can be done with Device Manager 'Update Driver Software - 802.11ac NIC' -> 'Browse my computer for driver software' wizard. What API can be used in C#?
The script is used to install a driver by adding the driver package to the driver store. Looking on how to achieve similar functionality using c# or C++.
# Define the path to the directory containing the driver files
$driverPath = "C:\Path\To\Driver"

# Add the driver package to the driver store
Write-Host "Adding driver package to the driver store..."
pnputil.exe /add-driver "$driverPath\*.inf" /subdirs /install


https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/pnputil-command-syntax

Found a partial solution using UpdateDriverForPlugAndPlayDevices function. On a Win64 system, the assembly should be compiled as x64. Although this does not completely replicate functionality of pnputil.exe, and it requires the device to be connected to the system.
[DllImport("Newdev.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool UpdateDriverForPlugAndPlayDevices(
   IntPtr hwndParent, 
   string HardwareId, 
   string FullInfPath, 
   uint InstallFlags, 
   IntPtr pRebootRequired);

internal static Action<string> Log = msg => Console.WriteLine(msg);

public static bool UpdateDeviceDriver(string infFilePath, string hardwareId)
{
    // Update the driver
    if (!UpdateDriverForPlugAndPlayDevices(IntPtr.Zero, hardwareId, infFilePath, 0, IntPtr.Zero))
    {
        LogWin32Error(nameof(UpdateDriverForPlugAndPlayDevices));
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

private static void LogWin32Error(string method)
{
    var code = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
    Log?.Invoke($"Error: {method} failed with error {code}.");
}


What is LogWin32Error in your answer? Seems like you missed that definition
